# Removing same files from folders

Tags: bash, shell

I'm using chroot to build packages for my own OS. I have the chroot in the archive file and at beginning of the building process this downloads twice and extracts. **I need a command, that deletes the files from the chroot folder, where the package was built, that are the same(for example by its hash) as in the second chroot folder.** I have tried several commands from Unix StackExchange, but none of them worked.

**edit: this must be fully automatic**

Comment: Some answers that you will have read almost certainly suggests using `fdupes` to find and remove duplicated files. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeah, I have. I used the command `fdupes --delete dir1 dir2`

Comment: What was the issue with doing it that way? If you want it to recurse and to delete without interactivity, use `-r` and `-N` in addition to `-d` (`--delete`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you do by comparing hash of all the files.

#### Method 1 (recommended):

Thanks to [Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) for suggesting to use `join` which simplifies the task. You can use following commands. Note that if any file has spaces in their name, this is not going to work.

```bsh
# DIR1 is the main directory
# DIR2 is from where files will get deleted. Change the values accordingly
DIR1="$PWD"
DIR2="$HOME"

find $DIR1 -type f | xargs md5sum 2>/dev/null | sort > /tmp/m1
find $DIR2 -type f | xargs md5sum 2>/dev/null | sort > /tmp/m2

join /tmp/m1 /tmp/m2 > /tmp/m3
cat /tmp/m3 | cut -d ' ' -f3 | xargs rm -f

# To delete empty directories
find $DIR2 -type d -empty -delete
```

#### Method 2:

Here we simply calculate hash of all files in both directories repeatedly and delete the file if they are same.

```bsh
# DIR1 is the main directory
# DIR2 is from where files will get deleted.
DIR1="$PWD"
DIR2="$HOME"

# Take a file from $DIR1 and check for it in $DIR2
for i in $DIR1/*; do
    HASH=$(md5sum $i 2>/dev/null | cut -d ' ' -f1 )
    if [ "$HASH" ]; then
        for j in $DIR2/*; do
            HASH2=$(md5sum $j | cut -d ' ' -f1)
            if [ "$HASH" = "$HASH2" ]; then
                # Delete files from $DIR2
                rm "$j"
            fi
        done
    fi
done
```

Comment: Why not simply compute the hashes _once_ and do a join (using `join`) between them? What you have written would compute the hashes of each file in  `$DIR2` as many times as there are files in `$DIR1`.  Also, you have issues with files that may have spaces etc. in their name due to not quoting properly. It's not clear in the question if this needs to be a recursive operation, but your code is not.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Spaces would be a problem with approach involving `cut`.

Comment: Also in the calls to `md5sum` and in the `for` loop headers.

Comment: This looks nice, but I only get these few messages, and only the one file mentioned in there get's removed(I have added echo "Removing $j" before the rm.(Shortened due the comment lenght)
2021-01-23T14:24:41.2819003Z md5sum: chroot/lib: Is a directory
2021-01-23T14:24:41.2839568Z md5sum: chroot/lib64: Is a directory
2021-01-23T14:24:41.2903282Z Deleting chroot/names
2021-01-23T14:24:41.2983764Z md5sum: chroot/sbin: Is a directory
2021-01-23T14:24:41.3000710Z md5sum: chroot/tmp: Is a directory
2021-01-23T14:24:41.3018971Z md5sum: chroot/usr: Is a directory

Comment: The problem is probably the thing, that it isn't recursive.

Comment: I have updated method 1 for recursive files This should work now. Pl try it. Haven't updated Method 2.

Comment: The thing you're using to delete empty directories at the end of "Method 1" will very likely delete _everything_ as it would start by calling `rm -r` for `$DIR2`.

Comment: Oh yes.. It would be better to delete empty directories with `find`

Answer (score 3):

With `fdupes`:

```
fdupes -drN dir1 dir2
```

This would delete everything in the two directories that are found more than once. The first found copy of any dupe is kept.

With long options:

```
fdupes --delete --recurse --noprompt dir1 dir2
```

Note that this also deletes files within `dir1` that are dupes of other files within that same directory.

On a system with GNU tools, you could work around the issue with deleting dupes in `dir1` if you script it yourself:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

dir1=somedir
dir2=someotherdir

sums1=$(mktemp)
sums2=$(mktemp)

# Remove temporary files when done.
trap 'rm -f "$sums1" "$sums2"' EXIT

# Calculate checksums for first directory, extract only the checksums
# themselves and sort them (removing duplicate checksums).
find "$dir1" -type f -exec md5sum -z {} + |
cut -z -c -32 |
sort -z -u -o "$sums1"

# Calculate the checksums for the second directory, and sort them.
find "$dir2" -type f -exec md5sum -z {} + |
sort -z -o "$sums2"

# Join the files on the first column, extract the pathnames for the
# files in the second directory that have the same checksum as files in
# the first directory, and delete these files.
join -z "$sums1" "$sums2" |
cut -z -c 34- |
xargs -0 rm -f


# Optionally, delete empty directories in the second directory
# find "$dir2" -type d -empty -delete
```

The code above additionally tries to make sure that any valid filename is properly handled by passing the pathnames around as nul-terminated lists.

---

Shorter `bash`-variant of the above script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

dir1=somedir
dir2=someotherdir

join -z \
    <(find "$dir1" -type f -exec md5sum -z {} + | cut -z -c -32 | sort -z -u)  \
    <(find "$dir2" -type f -exec md5sum -z {} + | sort -z) |
cut -z -c 34- |
xargs -0 rm -f
```

Comment: This doesn't work... Half of the files are still there( if I did it correctly, fdupes -drN folderWherePackageWasBuild originalFolder)

Comment: @rktech I can't see your files and I can only guess what directory you want to delete files out of. You may possibly have swapped the directories around. The `fdupes` utility will keep the _first_ copy of any dupe found, and it looks in the first directory first.

Comment: Ok, then it doesn't work, the first folder is set correctly.